# Use of undeclared identifier after replacing deprecated method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

code is as below:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
    // STUFF CONFIGURED HERE
}
return self;
}
```

Question:
since `initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` is deprecated

i use -`(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` instead

and then, the compiler reports an error that is " Use of undeclared identifier 'frame' "

could anyone tell me how could i handle the "frame"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

Does not provide the frame parameter (unlike the previous one, which did), yet your implementation is referring to a variable called `frame`, as such you're getting the error `Use of undeclared identifier 'frame'`

The frame can be changed via its `.frame` property, so it's the responsibility of the caller of `initWithStyle...` to set the frame. For a `UITableViewCell`, you typically don't need to set any frame, as the table view will manage it instead.

Might be worth having a look at the `init` documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html